# Delete facebook datas when logout iOS SDK

Tags: objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm really sorry for my english, but i'm italian.
i've got a view controller(C) that make the Facebook login and after that pass to a tab view controller(A) the id, userid and email variables, in a tab of that tab view controller(A) i've got another view controller(B) that contains a logout/login Facebook button, i need that when i press logout every Facebook variables stored on my app is deleted and when i log in store them again, this is what i tried :

```
#import "login.h"
#import "dashBoardViewController.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import "gestAccount.h"

@interface login ()

@end

@implementation login

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.loginButton.delegate = self;
    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"publish_actions",];


     self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];

    self.loginButton.delegate = self;
    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"publish_actions",];

    NSString *userid = ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).id;
    NSString *username = ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).first_name;
    _profilePicture.profileID = ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).id;
    _profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = _profilePicture.frame.size.width / 2;
    _profilePicture.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _profilePicture.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
    _profilePicture.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.nameLabel.text = username;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

    NSString *userName = [user first_name];
    NSString *userId = [user id];
    NSString *userEmail = [user objectForKey:@"email"];


    ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).first_name = userName;
    ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).id = userId;

    dashBoardViewController *dashBoardViewController =     [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashBoardViewController"];
    dashBoardViewController.first_name = userName;
    dashBoardViewController.id = userId;
    dashBoardViewController.userEmail = userEmail;
}



-(void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    self.profilePicture = nil;
    self.nameLabel.text = @"Loggati";
}

- (IBAction)gotoGestaccount:(id)sender {

    NSString *userid = ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).id;
    NSString *username = ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).first_name;


   gestAccount *gestaccount = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gestAccount"];
    gestaccount.first_name = username;
    gestaccount.id = userid;
    [self presentModalViewController:gestaccount animated:YES];
}


@end
```

but it doesn't work and it gives me this error on log :

> Warning: Attempt to present  on
>    whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

Comment: Hi Jack, could you clarify what you're trying to delete when the user logs out? Do you just want to delete the Facebook user's information from your own controllers?

Comment: yes, and i want to delete and replace the SharedPrefs informations @daviddoran